# Not able to access by IPv6 address by curl to Jboss server 8080 port

Tags: linux, apache, jboss, ipv6, firewall

In dual stack mode my server is accessible in both IPv4 and IPv6 address from same machine.

If I execute curl command to that server from another machine, only IPv4 is working IPv6 is not working it shows below error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to **{IPv6 address}** port 8080: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem

```
service ip6tables stop
```